# "go test github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go" failed

Tags: go, tensorflow, installation

I did these:

1. Installing TensorFlow on Mac OS X, following the steps.
2. Installing TensorFlow for Go, following the steps.

I get the following error:

```
macbookpro:~ fredlee$ go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
macbookpro:~ fredlee$ go test github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go

signal: killed
FAIL    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go  0.006s
```

Meanwhile, when I do this:

1. Installing TensorFlow for C, following the steps,

it works well.

```
macbookpro:Downloads fredlee$ ./a.out  
Hello from TensorFlow C library version 1.1.0 
macbookpro:Downloads fredlee$
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the Go version work?

Comment: Which version of the Go compiler are you using? It seems a number of OS X related issues were [fixed in the 1.8.1 release](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?page=1&q=milestone%3AGo1.8.1)

Comment: @ash thanks, currently i use go1.8,and have the above issue. after updating go1.8.3  i encounter another issue,  please view  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428816/tensorflow-for-go-demo-example-run-failed