# TensorFlow for Go demo example run failed

Tags: go, tensorflow

i have the issue.

environment

> ```
> macbookpro:lib fredlee$ go version
> go version go1.8.3 darwin/amd64
> macbookpro:lib fredlee$ pwd
> /usr/local/lib
> macbookpro:lib fredlee$ ls -alh libtensorflow.so 
> -r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   102M  1  1  1970 libtensorflow.so
> macbookpro:lib fredlee$ file libtensorflow.so 
> libtensorflow.so: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
> macbookpro:lib fredlee$
> ```

issue

```
> macbookpro:~ fredlee$ go get
> github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go macbookpro:~ fredlee$
> go test github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
> # github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go ld: library not found for -ltensorflow clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
> (use -v to see invocation)
> FAIL  github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go [build failed]
```

anyone can help me make it works?

Comment: i have export  two environment variables, it works well .                                                                                           macbookpro:lib fredlee$ export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
macbookpro:lib fredlee$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

> ld: library not found for -ltensorflow

When you run `go test` you're invoking the go compiler that compiles the required libraries, your test files and then executes them.

When you compile a program that uses a "non-pure" go library, you have to make the compiler (and the linker) aware of the library.

In the compilation phase, the compiler looks for the libraries (also) in the paths listed into the environment variable:

`LIBRARY_PATH` on OS X & Linux.

Thus you have to add into this variable the location of the compiled library.

For example I have:

```
TFGOLIB="${GOPATH}/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow"
export LIBRARY_PATH="${TFGOLIB}:${LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

During the runtime, instead, the os looks for the library in order to perform dynamic linking.

Thus you have to set this other variable (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on OS X) to the same location.

Moreover I suggest  you to also add the CUDA library path to this variable, in order to make it available at runtime.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib64:/opt/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/opt/cudnn5.1/cuda/lib64:${TFGOLIB}"
```

Comment: FYI: An alternative is to use `ldconfig`. Both the use of `ldconfig` and exporting `LIBRARY_PATH` should be mentioned in the installation instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_go

Answer (score 0):

I do not quit understand why you test a third-party package. But from your error, looks like a lib called `ld` is not found. If it is needed the the package, then I believe It should be installed in the $GOPATH/bin. So, please try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```